# MagicalRecord how to setup for new Swift Project using CocoaPods Use :branch => 'develop' i.e. 2.3.0-beta.5

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I've set up a new project to investigate Core Data with MagicalRecord compatibility. I'm specifying the 'develop' branch in the CocoaPod but I'm having issues with fetchRequests both using MyProjectName.MyManagedObject.MR_fetchAllSortedBy and MyManagedObject.MR_fetchAllSortedBy. I've created the MyManagedObject as a Swift file and the -ObjC flag is set in the other linker flags. The error seen is: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'A fetch request must have an entity.'
The CoreData stack is set up successfully. The failure occurs within MagicalRecord at the fetch request.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `@objc(<class name>)` prefix for your NSManagedObject class will fix `executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.` error when fetching entity.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(AccountEntity) class AccountEntity: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var createdAt: NSDate
    @NSManaged var name: String

}
```

Comment: This should definitely be an accepted answer. I'm still unclear why do we need to add class name after "@objc", "@objc(AccountEntity)" instead just "@objc" but it works!